# LWC Responsive Tables In Light DOM

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, table, lwc-dom

I'm trying to build a div-based responsive table in LWC using Salesforce's new "Light DOM" feature. Unfortunately the table won't render properly, it looks like this:

[image]

Following is the html-layout:

**datatable.html**

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
  <div class="dtContainer">
    <div class="dt">
      <div class="dtRow_Header">
        <template for:each={columns} for:item="cellHeadData">
          <c-dt-cell-head cell-head-data={cellHeadData} key={cellHeadData.value}></c-dt-cell-head>
        </template>
      </div>
      <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
        <div class="dtRow" key={record.value}>
          <c-dt-row row-data={record} key={record.value}></c-dt-row>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**datatable.css**

```
.dtContainer
{
  width: 300px;
}

.dt, .dtRow_Header, .dtRow, .dtCell, .dtCell_Header
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.dt
{
  display: table;
}

.dtCell, .dtCell_Header
{
  display: table-cell;
}

.dtCell_Header
{
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: slategrey;
}

.dtRow_Header
{
  display: table-header-group;
}

.dtRow
{
  display: table-row;
}

.cellData
{
  resize: horizontal;
}
```

**dtCellHead.html**

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
  <div class="dtCell_Header">
    {cellHeadData.label}
  </div>
</template>
```

**dtRow.html**

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
  <template for:each={rowData} for:item="cellData">
    <c-dt-cell cell-data={cellData} key={cellData.value}></c-dt-cell>
  </template>
</template>
```

**dtCell.html**

```
<template lwc:render-mode="light">
  <div class="dtCell">
    {cellData.value}
  </div>
</template>
```

Current complete source code can be found here: https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/Z3GKaegupu2pTukJPlqm/src/app.html

Seems like it is not really handled as a table but I do not know why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thx for this interesting question! Just a remark: In the example you provide on studio.webcomponents.dev is a small mistake: `<div class="dtRow">` exists both on the level of datatable.html and dtRow. Your point remains valid.